# Specific Heat of SYK Model

Tags: condensed-matter, field-theory, ads-cft

For the [SYK model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachdev%E2%80%93Ye%E2%80%93Kitaev_model), One can prove that for $N\to \infty$ the total energy can be written as the derivative of the imaginary time Green's function ([see related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/503105/trick-for-calculating-the-thermal-entropy-of-the-syk-model-in-the-large-n-limi)):
$$\langle H \rangle=\frac{N}{4} \partial_\tau G(\tau)\big|_{\tau\to 0} $$

Similarly, we can find a formula in terms of real time Green functions of the form:
$$\langle H \rangle=\frac{N}{4}\partial_t G^K(t)\big|_{t\to 0}$$

Where $G^K$ is the Keldysh Green function defined as:
$$G^K(t)=-\frac{i}{N}\sum_i \big(\langle \chi_i(t) \chi_i(0)\rangle - \langle \chi_i(0) \chi_i(t) \rangle \big)$$
If we go to the frequency space and use fluctuation dissipation theorem we get:
$$\langle H \rangle=\frac{N}{2}\int \omega \, \mathrm{Im}G^R(\omega)\, \tanh(\frac{\omega}{2T})\, \frac{d\omega}{2\pi}$$
Now, if I want to find the specific heat, I have to calculate $\frac{\partial \langle H \rangle}{\partial T}$ which will give me:

$$C=\frac{N}{2}\int \omega \, \frac{\partial \mathrm{Im}G^R(\omega)}{\partial T}\, \tanh(\frac{\omega}{2T})\, \frac{d\omega}{2\pi}-\frac{N}{4T^2}\int \frac{\omega^2 \, \mathrm{Im}G^R(\omega)}{ \cosh^2(\frac{\omega}{2T})}\, \frac{d\omega}{2\pi}$$
The first term, which comes from the change in the spectrum as we change $T$ is not easy to compute. But we can find the scaling of the second term with $T$, by noting that the integral is both UV and IR finite, since for SYK:
$$ \lim_{\omega\to 0}\mathrm{Im}G^R(\omega) \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{|\omega|}}$$
Therefore:
$$\frac{N}{4T^2}\int \frac{\omega^2 \, \mathrm{Im}G^R(\omega)}{ \cosh^2(\frac{\omega}{2T})}\, \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} \sim T^{1/2}$$

The first term is important only if scales with a smaller power of $T$. But, the well known result for SYK is that $C\sim T$.

What is the source of error in my calculation?